# Azure VM writing to a the filesystem from ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I am newpie to Windows Azure. I have an application on my server that I moved to the VM not using the visual studio integration or packaging just copied the application and set all the things related to it, part of my application I write to a specific file   - I know it is not a good idea but I am doing it for the fun. The folder access is set such that everybody can write to it (Actually it was set such that the apppool can write to it then I made it such that everybody can write to it on the Azure). 
The code is something like this

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    stream.Position = stream.Length;
    stream.Write(RawBytes, 0, RawBytes.Length);
    stream.WriteByte(13);
    stream.WriteByte(10);
}
```

it works fine on my machine but on the azure VM for some reason it is not working I know that Azure using a different storage mechanism, can someone guide me to what to do exactly

Comment: If you change your `FileMode` to `FileMode.Append` you can avoid the line that moves the stream position to the end.

Answer (score 1):

When running an application in the cloud you have a number of different options for managing persistence and surely writing to the local file system is one option. If however you need to access that file from multiple VM's or from on-premises you will have problems. For this reason we have created the Azure Files Service (see [Getting Started with Files](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)) which allows you to create an SMB file share that you can then read / write to using standard windows API's from multiple VMs. This is particularly useful for migrating existing on-premises applications to the cloud.

For new applications you probably want to consider using one of our other storage options - including [Azure Blobs, Tables, Queues](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/storage/), [SQL Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/) or [Doc DB](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/documentdb/) etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you do not have the right permissions on your azure VM. You can write to the file system on a azure VM. One option is to write to the windows Temp directory:

```
var filepath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, "some text");
```

For more options you can read: [azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure](http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/)